# How to get the integral (function) from a vector?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I have a vector than can be plotted and I would like to compute its integral. I don't mean the total area below, but how it evolves over the domain of integration. Basically, its "indefinite" integral. Is this possible? maybe via interpolation? Since I am working with Chebyshev differentiation matrices, do you know if there is an equivalent for integration?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [`cumtrapz`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html):

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000); % example x axis values
y = sin(x); % example function
I = cumtrapz(x, y); % compute its integral
plot(x, y, x, I) % plot them
grid on % grid
```

[image]